# solution of some total differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I can't find the integrating factor of the following differential equations:
$dx + (x+z)dy + dz=0$
$z^3dx + zdy -2ydz =0$
$(x+z)^2dy +y^2dx + y^2dz=0$
$xdx + ydy + (x^2 + y^2 + z^2 +1)dz=0$
Thank you.

Comment: yes, but I got stuck on these 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: For the fist equation, you have $\frac{d(x+z)}{x+z}=-dy$. And you do something similar to others.

Basically you need to complete the integrals, keep the formulae as follows in mind: \begin{align}
xdy+ydx=d(xy),~~~~
\frac{ydx-xdy}{y^2}=d(\frac{x}{y}),~~~\cdots
\end{align}

Comment: thank you for your answer, I was able to solve the first one but I don't understand how am I supposed to find a similar pattern for the others?

Comment: thank you, I got the second one! For the 3rd one, how can I integrate dy/y^2=-(dx+dz)/(x+z)^2 ?

Comment: @user76741, sure, you are on the track.

Comment: sorry, just realized that it was a stupid question :)

Comment: I am really sorry but can you give me a hint on the last one?

Comment: @user76741, it seems the last one is missing something. Are you sure you typed it correctly?

Comment: yes, I checked it...

Comment: @user76741, if it is correct, then we will end up getting $d(x^2+y^2)/dz+2(x^2+y^2)=-2z^2-2$. By letting $x^2+y^2=u$ you will get $du/dz+2u=-2z^2-2$, which is a first order ODE, if you have learnt how to solve.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I ended up solving it...

Comment: @user76741, you're welcome.